# g++ 4.9.3 complains that friended ctor is private with .emplace_back(), but likes .push_back()

Tags: c++, stl, emplace

I must be missing one of the finer points regarding emplace() and friends. Here's a complete, minimal example that reproduces the problem with g++ 4.9.3:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    class Bar
    {
    private:
    friend class Foo;
        Bar(Foo &foo) : foo(foo) {}
        Foo &foo;
    };

    Bar &getBar()
    {
        //bars.push_back(*this);        // works fine
        bars.emplace_back(*this);       // Foo::Bar::Bar(Foo&) is private
        return bars.back();
    }
private:
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
};
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't change your questions after receiving answers. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `emplace_back`, the container is the one that constructs the `Bar`. But that constructor is private and the container is not a friend, so it fails.

But `push_back(*this)` is equivalent to `push_back(Bar(*this))`. That is, it's the `Foo` that's doing the construction and it is a friend.

Comment: Impressive. Any thoughts on how to make the container a friend?

Comment: @Steger you can't guarantee that it would work, since it could be an unspecified base class that does the construction.

Answer (score 2):

```
    bars.emplace_back(*this);
```

delays the call to the constructor `Bar(Foo&)` to `std::vector::emplace_back()`. That function does not have the access privilege to call `Bar(Foo&)`.

On the other hand,

```
    bars.push_back(*this);
```

calls the constructor `Bar(Foo&)` before the call to `std::vector::push_back()`. That is not a problem since `Foo` is a `friend` of `Bar`.